# Mac git client Tower dont sync folders from repository

Tags: git, macos, git-tower

I'm using git client Tower for mac os

We have git ce server where repositories are stored

Yesterday I noticed that git during pull dont pull new folders with files from git but only changes in files

Folders are not empty

How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "git during pull dont pull new folders with files from git"? Could you describe the state of the remote remote repository and what you expect to happen when you do `git pull`?

Answer (score 0):

We'd need more information on this to be able to fully understand the issue. Can you please:

1. Open the repository in Tower
2. Go to File -> Open in Terminal
3. Execute the command `git pull origin branch_name` (replace 'branch_name' with the name of your branch).

Does this pull all the information you expect? If not, can you please check that you are on the correct branch locally? (For example, if your remote is `develop`, does Tower show `develop` as your local `HEAD` branch as well?)
What does the command `git status` show you?

Feel free to reach out to us via https://www.git-tower.com/support/help-center/ with more details so we can look into this for you. A screen recording or screenshot would be very helpful!